# Reserving IP Range in Home Routers

Tags: router, ip-address

I would like to ask how can I reserve an IP Range on a home router? For example, I have a Cisco RV215W, and I would like the IP Range 192.168.1.100 - 192.168.1.115 to NOT be distributed by the router, and instead start at .116.

Comment: Can you modify your settings so that DHCP range begins from .116?

Comment: What router model and software version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this by changing the DHCP pool range. Per the administration guide for the [Cisco RV215W](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/routers/csbr/rv215w/administration/guide/en/rv215w_admin_en.pdf), you can do this by go to **Network** > **LAN** > **LAN Configuration**, then change **Starting IP Address** to 192.168.1.116. You may need to also adjust the max # DHCP users if you don't want to the pool to extend past its original end value.

Comment: Hi, if I do this, will I be able to use the IP range .100 - .115 as static? I am trying to do this because I would like to have my printer's IP addresses fixed. Because sometimes when their IP address's changes, I need to reconnect/re-add them to be able to print.

Comment: Yes, you can go into the Static DHCP settings to assign an address to a particular MAC address. Please note that you might not need to reduce the DHCP pool range unless you've already used all the other available IP addresses (i.e. anything from 192.168.1.1 through to 192.168.1.99 can also be assigned, as can any address after the end of the DHCP pool up to 192.168.1.254).

Comment: "Yes, you can go into the Static DHCP settings to assign an address to a particular MAC address", Just to clarify Sir, DHCP settings on the router or on the device that I would like to set the IP address? Thanks again!

Comment: DHCP server settings are all configured on the router. From the client end, you just set everything to "automatic" and the router tells it what to do.